# Entity Framework always adds new row for virtual property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two entities

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Material
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Weight { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual MaterialCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class MaterialCategory
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
```

And when i add new Material entity with reference to MaterialCategory object that already exist in database entity framework create new row in MaterialCategory table and set reference of Material.CategoryId to newly creadted MaterialCategory row.
Please help me in this situation

Comment: Add the ForeignKey attribute to the Category property or use Fluent API. You can read more on this on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#relationships

Comment: Thank u @codemonkey for your reply. EF maked this Foreign keys after inital migration (i can see it in my database). I tried to add atribute [ForeignKey] to Category property and after run add-migration commad and there was no pending changes